# Selenium Webdriver unable to recognize elements of Oracle WAM Application

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm in the process of automating an Oracle WAM application (built using Oracle Utility Application Framework). I tried various options using id, xpath, css etc. Unfortunately, it does not recognize.

Can someone provide me with tips?

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    String Act_Title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(Act_Title);

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("Input.oj-inputsearch-input"))).sendKeys("Purchase");


    //WebElement SearchElement =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Input.oj-inputsearch-input"));
    //SearchElement.sendKeys("Purchase");


    /*WebElement MainBar=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.leftToolbarArea"));
    WebElement root=MainBar.findElement(By.cssSelector("id#IM_menuButton"));
    root.click();
    Actions A=new Actions(driver);
    A.moveToElement(root).build().perform();*/

    /*driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ouafButton toolbarButton simpleToolbarButton menuImg")).click();*/
```

---

Thanks
Nagendra

Comment: Is there an error message you can potentially post the full version of?

Comment: Thanks.. it worked now.. Looks like its something to do with the frame settings.

Comment: great! If you want, can post your own answer and accept after a total of 48 hours has passed from when you asked the question. This could end up helping someone else in the future :)

Comment: This was resolved using the following

Comment: //Requistion Type
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  //Switch to current frame
  driver.switchTo().frame("uiMap");
  
  //navigate to the Main section
  WebElement PR_Main=driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div[3]");
  PR_Main.click();

Comment: That’s good. Hopefully your answer will help others out in the future. :)